# How to clear save file dialog filename in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I would like to able to clear my save file dialog filename in wxPython. What I mean is say that if I do

```py
saveFileDialog.GetFilename()
```

Say this returns

> test.txt

How can I make it so when I do GetFilename() again, it will return

```
""
```

and not

> test.txt

? I'm not really sure how to go about this, but thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I use the SetFilename method to reset the path

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.size = (400, 1000)
        self.Title = 'wx App'
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_quit_click)

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()
        self.save_dialog = wx.FileDialog(self, style=wx.FD_SAVE)

    def on_save(self, event):
        self.save_dialog.ShowModal()

    def on_check(self, event):
        print(f'filename={self.save_dialog.GetFilename()}')
        self.save_dialog.SetFilename('')

    def on_quit_click(self, event):
        del event
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent
        # self.file_picker = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self, style=wx.FLP_SAVE)
        btn_save = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_SAVE)
        btn_save.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.parent.on_save)
        btn_check = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_OK)
        btn_check.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.parent.on_check)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # sizer.Add(self.file_picker)
        sizer.Add(btn_save)
        sizer.Add(btn_check)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
wx_app = wx.App()
MainFrame()
wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am about to try this and I will let you know if this works. From my logic this looks like it will work so I will give you to answer anyways.